# How to fix np. where functions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My Data frame looks like -

```
id      marital_status       age        city1         city2
1           Married          32           7             64
2           Married          34           8             39
3           Single           53           0             72
4           Divorce          37           2             83
5           Divorce          42           10            52
6           Single           29           3             82
7           Married          37           8             64
```

Size of the data frame is 22.4 Million records.

My objective is based on the conditional statement my final data frame looks like -

```
id      marital_status       age        city1         city2        present
1           Married          32           12            64           1
2           Married          34           8             39           0
3           Single           53           0             72           0
4           Divorce          37           2             83           0
5           Divorce          42           10            52           0
6           Single           29           3             82           0
7           Married          37           8             64           1
```

What I have done so far -

```
test_df = pd.read_csv('city.csv')

condition = ((test_df['city1'] >= 5) &\
            (test_df['marital_status'] == 'Married') &\
            (test_df['age'] >= 32))


test_df.loc[:, 'present'] = test_df.where(condition, 1)
```

But got NA values in 'present' columns

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `np.where` function, but `DataFrame.where` in your solution.

I think you need set values by condition:

```
test_df['present'] = np.where(condition, 1, 0)
```

Or cast `True/False` to `1/0` by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
test_df['present'] = condition.astype(int)
```

---

```
print (test_df)
   id marital_status  age  city1  city2  present
0   1        Married   32     12     64        1
1   2        Married   34      8     39        1
2   3         Single   53      0     72        0
3   4        Divorce   37      2     83        0
4   5        Divorce   42     10     52        0
5   6         Single   29      3     82        0
6   7        Married   37      8     64        1
```

Comment: It's not working.My initial data frame don't have 'present' column.But I want that column in my final data frame

Comment: @JohnDavis - Changed solution, please refresh page.